# I'd like to have a checkbox on one sheet send information to another sheet in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I want to have a database of materials I use often with other information like cost, relail and available lengths et cetera. Then check the box next to it and have it populate on another sheet ready to have quantity adjusted. It's for an estimator I'm going to start putting together but this step underpins the whole thing and I don't know how to go about it as I am an HVAC tech and not a professional programmer. I looked through a library of functions and nothing jumped out at me and most of them are quite foreign to me.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your post does not have enough information for us to help you. An example of your data along with the expected outcome would assist us in assisting you. Also, it is usually more useful for you when you try something first and post that along with what it doesn't do that you need. Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Comment: I've read the how to ask section but I really don't know how to ask properly. I'll try to boil it down as much as possible. I want to know if I can click on an item in a list and have the contents of the row populate in a different spot. I'll continue to persue this until I can ask a competent question. In the meantime if you have any suggestions it would be much appreciated.